# How do we create a function for the recurrence relation in terms of a dependent variable?

Tags: functions, syntax, documentation

Suppose

```
S = {{-1.5, 1}, {0, 1}, {1.5, 1}, {1.5, 0.1}, {0, -0.1}, {-1.5, 0}, {1, -1.4}, {-1, -1.5}}
```

How do we define the recurrence relation as a function of the dependent variable

```
T = Table[{
   X[1, q] = S[[q]], 
   Y[1, q] = DeleteCases[S, X[1, q]], 
   X[x_, q] := Nearest[Y[x - 1, q], X[x - 1, q], 1][[1]],
   Y[x_, q] := DeleteCases[Y[x - 1, q], X[x, q]],
   P[q] = Table[X[x, q], {x, 1, Length[S]}]}, {q,1,Length[S]}]
Table[T[[r, 5]], {r, 1, Length[S]}]
```

I don't wish to use `T[[r, 5]]`, instead I want to define a function for the recurrence relation in terms of a dependent variable.

Note the output should be:

```
out=
{{{-1.5, 1}, {-1.5, 0}, {0, -0.1}, {0, 1}, {1.5, 1}, {1.5, 0.1}, {1, -1.4}, 
{-1, -1.5}}, {{0, 1}, {0, -0.1}, {-1.5, 0}, {-1.5,1}, {-1, -1.5}, {1, -1.4}, 
{1.5, 0.1}, {1.5, 1}}, {{1.5, 1}, {1.5, 0.1}, {0, -0.1}, {0, 1}, {-1.5, 1}, 
{-1.5, 0}, {-1, -1.5}, {1, -1.4}}, {{1.5, 0.1}, {1.5, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, -0.1}, 
{-1.5, 0}, {-1.5, 1}, {-1, -1.5}, {1, -1.4}}, {{0, -0.1}, {0, 1}, {-1.5, 1}, 
{-1.5,0}, {-1, -1.5}, {1, -1.4}, {1.5, 0.1}, {1.5, 1}}, {{-1.5,0}, {-1.5, 1},
 {0, 1}, {0, -0.1}, {1.5, 0.1}, {1.5, 1}, {1, -1.4}, {-1, -1.5}}, {{1, -1.4},
 {1.5, 0.1}, {1.5, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, -0.1}, {-1.5, 0}, {-1.5, 1}, {-1, -1.5}},
 {{-1, -1.5}, {-1.5, 0}, {-1.5, 1}, {0,1}, {0, -0.1}, {1.5, 0.1}, {1.5, 1},
{1, -1.4}}}
```

Is there a simpler code?

**Edit:** With each iteration, the recurrence relation `X` start at the next point of list `S`. For example,`X[1,1]={-1.5,1}` (the first point of `S`), `X[1,2]={0,1}` (the second point of `S`), `X[1,3]={1.5,1}` (the third point of `S`), etc.

Comment: Can you please: **(1)** Describe in words what you want? **(2)** Show what the desired output looks like? Thanks.

Comment: @Syed I made corrections. I have a hard time describing what I want but the output is there.

Comment: Label your output as `out`. `ListLinePlot[S, PlotStyle -> Red]` and `ListLinePlot /@ out`. Can you describe how the result is evolving with each iteration as it is still unclear?

Comment: @Syed I added an explanation at the bottom. There's no need to compare the points in `S` with the points `out`.